# Always use a UUID for the id property of JPA entities and base equals and hashcode on it?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

There are a [lot of articles](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) that cover how to implement `hashcode` and `equals` for JPA entities.

Instead of worrying about this for every single JPA entity created, would it be simpler to set a `final` and `updatable = false`  `id` property to a `UUID` and base the `hashcode` and `equals` implementations on that id?  Any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Comment: Seems the consensus is that it is a good ideas based on [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352023/using-uuid-as-business-key-and-equals-hashmethod).

Answer (score 2):

Why add a new extra column or use UUID which does not play well with MySQL clustered indexes when you can implement `equals` and `hashCode` based on the `AUTO_INCREMENTED` or SEQUENCE-based Primary Key?

So, this is how your implementations would look like:

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Identifiable<Long> {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), book.getId());
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The constant `getClass().hashCode()` value is for making sure it is consistent across all entity state transitions.